# Kotlin Type inference by inline generic function

Tags: kotlin

I simplified the code where I reached the problem, so lets say I've got 2 generic interfaces:

```
interface Interface1<T>
interface Interface2<T>
```

It doesn't matter if they have any methods or not. Then I created inline generic function to create universal object, that implements all interfaces I need:

```
private inline fun <reified T> createValue() = object : Interface1<T>, Interface2<T> { }
```

And then I added property in class that initialized with this function. Now it's important to use automatic type inferring here:

```
private val testPropertyInt = createValue<Int>()
```

All this code will be compiled. And that's enough to raise `VerifyError` in constructor call. If I say what type this property should be there wouldn't be any error:

```
private val testPropertyInt: Interface1<Int> = createValue<Int>()
```

May be it can be usefull if I place full code here:

```
interface Interface1<T>
interface Interface2<T>

class KotlinBugTest {
    private val testPropertyInt = createValue<Int>()

    @Test
    fun testBug() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
    }

    private inline fun <reified T> createValue() = object : Interface1<T>, Interface2<T> { }
}
```

**And the question is:**

Why can it be compiled though it can't work with that type in runtime? I [posted an issue on *JetBrains* tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32711), hope they will do something about that.

Comment: is there any reasons to use `reified` and `inline`? because without these it works good

Comment: I tried like this `inline fun <reified T> combine():Any = object: InterfaceA<T>, InterfaceB<T>{} ` and then accessing `combine<Int>() as InterfaceA<Int>` and it works.

Comment: @Eugene, yes I've got reasons to use `reified` in my real code unlike in this simplified one. So just trust me :)

Comment: @SuryavelTR, surely there is no error if directly point a type of this property - I mentioned it in my question. I just want to know about type inferring error.